# ANCOVA (ANalysis of COVAriance)

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

I have two time series of the form

```
{time, value}
```

I have linear fits of each set individually, and I am interested in the statistical differences between the slopes, with the intercept of no interest, so I would like to do an ANCOVA type thing, following what is outlined here
http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/StatisticalModelAnalysis/ComputeAndVisualizeResultsForAnANCOVAModel.html

I can join into a larger set with a third column to distinguish the type

```
{type, time, value}
```

I end up using `LinearModelFit` as follows:

```
result = LinearModelFit[data, {type, time}, {type, time}, 
NominalVariables -> type];
result["BestFitParameters"];
result["ANOVATable"]
```

which all runs fine, but clearly this process only analyzes differences in the intercept (i.e., the best fit parameters have the same slope but different intercept), which I guess makes sense given how regression and ANOVA are related - my question is how would I re-do this so as to get the stats on the slopes instead?

Ideally I'd like to extend this to a two-factor equivalent, where there are two type factors, each with two sub-factors, and see if the slopes vary depending on which way you slice up the data.

Comment: Problem solved: forgot to include interaction term, so LMF should read
      `LinearModelFit[data, {type, time,time*type}, {type, time}` Derp!